# How would I check for a Granted Authority with Spring Security with the tag library?

Tags: spring-security, el

I have a set of jQuery tabs. I only want some of these tags to show when they have the correct granted authority impl. Is it possible to check by using EL in the security tags, or do I need to add another role and check by that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use EL:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>

<sec:authorize access="hasRole('authority_name_you_want_to_check_for')">
   content conditional on having required authority
</sec:authorize>
```

Comment: But that is for roles, not authorities, no? I already tried this against the GrantedAuthority class name and it didn't work.

Comment: You mean you want to check for a specific class type in the authorities list? No, there's no builtin expression that will do that. You'd need to implement either a custom tag or a helper class with a static method you could invoke from an expression.